# SonarLint Analysis failed when using VS Code extension for JavaScript files

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I've tried to set up the [SonarLint Extension](https://www.sonarlint.org/vscode/) for **Visual Studio Code** on Windows, and followed the instructions to use Connected mode. I think I've set it up correctly because in the  SonarLint output logs, shows some 200 status codes for connecting to my organisation server (FYI I changed the URL in the log below):

```
Connected SonarLint engine started for example-project
GET 200 http://example.com/sonar/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=example-project | time=152ms
GET 200 http://example.com/sonar/api/properties?format=json&resource=example-project | time=70ms
GET 200 http://example.com/sonar/api/components/tree.protobuf?qualifiers=BRC&baseComponentKey=example-project&ps=500&p=1 | time=78ms
GET 200 example.com/sonar/batch/issues?key=example-project | time=74ms
```

It then shows that it's trying to analyse a file that I have open:

```
Analysis triggered on file:///c%3A/Users/example/src/example/src/js/example.js with configuration: 
[
  moduleKey: example
  baseDir: c:\Users\example\src\example
  workDir: c:\Users\example\src\example\.sonarlint
  extraProperties: {}
  inputFiles: [
    c:\Users\example\src\example\src\js\example.js (UTF-8)
  ]
]
```

However, it then shows the following error messages:

```
Available languages:
  * JavaScript => "js"
  * Java => "java"
Start analysis
Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to js: **/*.js
Declared extensions of language Java were converted to java: **/*.java,**/*.jav
Quality profiles:
  * java: java-sonar-way-77058 (251 rules)
  * js: js-sonar-way-33138 (86 rules)
[Info  - 10:43:48 AM] Index files
Language of file 'file:///c:\Users\example\src\example\src\js\example.js' is set to 'js'
Setting filesystem encoding: UTF-8
[Info  - 10:43:48 AM] 1 files indexed
'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
Execute Sensor: JavaScript Squid Sensor
[Info  - 10:43:49 AM] 1 source files to be analyzed
Initializing metadata of file file:///c:\Users\example\src\example\src\js\example.js
[Error - 10:43:50 AM] Analysis failed.
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to analyse file: c:\Users\example\src\example\src\js\example.js
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.analyse(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:174)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.analyseFiles(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:133)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.execute(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:349)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:52)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.AllSensorsExecutor.executeSensor(AllSensorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.AllSensorsExecutor.execute(AllSensorsExecutor.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.analyzer.sensor.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.analysis.AnalysisContainer.doAfterStart(AnalysisContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:110)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.storage.StorageAnalyzer.analyze(StorageAnalyzer.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.storage.StorageContainerHandler.analyze(StorageContainerHandler.java:76)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.lambda$analyze$0(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:152)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.withReadLock(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:339)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.withReadLock(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:329)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.analyze(ConnectedSonarLintEngineImpl.java:150)
    at org.sonarlint.languageserver.SonarLintLanguageServer$ConnectedAnalysisWrapper.analyze(SonarLintLanguageServer.java:718)
    at org.sonarlint.languageserver.SonarLintLanguageServer$ConnectedAnalysisWrapper.analyze(SonarLintLanguageServer.java:699)
    at org.sonarlint.languageserver.SonarLintLanguageServer.analyze(SonarLintLanguageServer.java:605)
    at org.sonarlint.languageserver.SonarLintLanguageServer.didOpen(SonarLintLanguageServer.java:539)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.lambda$null$0(GenericEndpoint.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.services.GenericEndpoint.notify(GenericEndpoint.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.handleNotification(RemoteEndpoint.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.RemoteEndpoint.consume(RemoteEndpoint.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.Launcher$Builder.lambda$wrapMessageConsumer$0(Launcher.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.validation.ReflectiveMessageValidator.consume(ReflectiveMessageValidator.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.handleMessage(StreamMessageProducer.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 12 is not a valid line offset for pointer. File [path=c:\Users\example\src\example\src\js\example.js] has 1 character(s) at line 105
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.checkValid(DefaultInputFile.java:312)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newPointer(DefaultInputFile.java:246)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInputFile.java:261)
    at org.sonar.javascript.cpd.CpdVisitor.visitNode(CpdVisitor.java:80)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:74)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:94)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.api.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:62)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.scanFile(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:235)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.JavaScriptSquidSensor.analyse(JavaScriptSquidSensor.java:163)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: hello. can you share the file which is failing? Also what is the SonarJS version on the SonarQube server you are connecting to? Does it fail on the same file when you are not in the connected mode?

Comment: @TiborBlenessy thanks for your reply, the SonarJS version on the SonarQube server is `2.19.0.3866`. This issue happens on every JS, and it only happens when in connected mode, it works fine when not in connected mode.

Comment: Can you try to upgrade SonarJS on the server side? The version you are using is very old.

Comment: @TiborBlenessy we updated to SonarJS: 5.0 Build 6962, and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the problem was that the server it was trying to connect to was on an old version of SonarJS. We updated it to `SonarJS: 5.0 Build 6962`, and now the SonarLint extension for VS Code works perfectly in connected mode.